# Import Certain data into a json file

Tags: json, import, sublimetext3

I'm trying to import some data from [here](https://data.austintexas.gov/dataset/Restaurant-Inspection-Scores/ecmv-9xxi)  and I want to put it in my json file.

As you can see, a restaurant can have many rows of data from its inspection dates and scores. However, I only want to import the restaurant name, its address, and its most recentest inspection score. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

I was thinking of copy the data into sublime text and somehow delete the duplicate lines? However, I'm not too sure how I would do it.

I'm pretty sure on the website there's a easy way for me to do it but I just can't figure out how.

An example of what I want is:

```
markers = [
{
    "name": "360 Pizza, LLC",
    "address": "360 Pizza, Austin",
    "score": "81",
    "lat": 30.36032,
    "lng": -97.7901
}
```

I'm currently working on an interactive map using Leaflet and my data is in a json file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the link in your question and click on the pretty sky blue "Export" button at the top right, you can download the dataset as JSON [right here](https://data.austintexas.gov/api/views/ecmv-9xxi/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD). I'll leave it up to you to process the dataset to obtain the information you need.

Comment: I'm not sure how to separate out the data from the ones I need?

Comment: @user3128376 I don't either. You know your requirements best.